# Force https redirect on all http requests on IIS

Tags: asp.net, https, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I want to force all http requests to redirect to https, so I now have this rule:

```
  <rules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="force https" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(sitea\.com)|(sitea\.uk)|(sitea\.org)" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
  </rules>
```

But when I request for example `http://www.sitea.com`, it does not redirect to `https://www.sitea.com`.
(on a sidenote: I was also wondering if this has any negative effect on SEO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we use

```
<rule name="httpsredirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I can see a few differences - we have {R:1} where you have {REQUEST_URI}  and we just have one condition entered which turns off https so only the http is redirected, that is perhaps where you are going wrong.

As for SEO - that is a big subject - but since you are doing a Permanent redirect, the search engines will recognize that and take the url out of their index, and use the https one instead.